# Complex number modulo real number

Tags: complex-numbers

I get that
a = b (mod x) means a and b have to same remainder when divided by x. But when we are dealing with complex number, what does mod even mean? if a = 3+4i, what does 3+4i mod 5 mean? how do you divide complex number by real number and have a remainder?

Particularly, how do we prove that

$$(3+4i)^n\equiv 3+4i \pmod 5$$

where $n>0$?

I am just trying to grasp what it means to have a remainder when you divide a complex number by a real number.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Such expressions should be defined in context,  Here it appears to mean that there are integers $a_n,b_n$ such that $(3+4i)^n=3+4i+5(a_n+b_ni)$.  For example, with $n=2$ we have $(3+4i)^2=-7+24i=(3+4i)-10 +20i=(3+4i)+5(-2+4i)$.

Comment: Side note:  having proven it for $n=2$, general $n$ follows by a quick induction.